# How does the l1 norm exclude outliers?

Tags: statistics, optimization

I have read that using the l1 norm is useful as it excludes the effect of outliers when, for example, finding a linear approximation to a set of data points. However, I can't quite see how this works.

Any hints?

Comment: Where have you read this?

Answer (score 4):

The $\ell_1$-norm is less sensitive to outliers than the $\ell_2$-norm.  For example, suppose that we are trying to find a vector $x$ such that $Ax \approx b$, but certain components of $b$ are "wrong" or corrupted.  So it's ok for $(Ax - b)_i$ to be large if the $i$th component of $b$ is corrupted -- we only care about agreement with the uncorrupted components of $b$.

We could try minimizing $\| Ax - b \|_2^2$, but the $\ell_2$-norm simply hates for any of the components of the residual $Ax - b$ to be large, because the $\ell_2$-norm squares those components, making them huge -- a disaster.  The $\ell_1$-norm, on the other hand, does not mind so much if some of the components of the residual $Ax - b$ are large.  (Those large components don't get squared, so it's not such a big deal.)

The $\ell_1$-norm is also more irritated by small components in the residual than the $\ell_2$-norm.  (The $\ell_2$-norm squares small components, making them tiny and negligible.)  So the $\ell_1$-norm is willing to have a few components of the residual be large (not a disaster), if it helps to avoid having a lot of small nonzero components (which would be quite irritating).

A slightly different viewpoint is that penalizing the $\ell_1$-norm of the residual $Ax - b$ encourages the residual $Ax - b$ to be sparse: most components equal to $0$, with a few large components allowed.  That's just what we want to happen if a few of the components of $b$ are outliers.  You can find a picture [here](https://www.quora.com/Why-is-L1-regularization-supposed-to-lead-to-sparsity-than-L2) (and similar pictures elsewhere) that help to explain why penalizing the $\ell_1$-norm promotes sparsity.

Another useful penalty function is the Huber penalty, which is a smoothed out version of the $\ell_1$-norm.  It's like the $\ell_1$-norm, except it's quadratic near the origin.  The Huber penalty, like the $\ell_1$-norm, is not so sensitive to outliers.

This is discussed more thoroughly in chapter 6 of Boyd and Vandenberghe.  See figure 6.5 and 6.2, for example.

Comment: +1, I was thinking about regularization and not just just using the $\ell^1$-norm in $\|Ax-b\|_1$ which is, indeed, most probably what the OP was asking, I removed my answer accordingly

Answer (score 0):

A better way to look at this is to note that the $\ell_1$ norm (or *absolute error*) is minimized by the *median* of the target distribution. See [Why does minimizing the MAE lead to forecasting the median and not the mean?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/355538/1352) Therefore, for instance, the $\ell_1$ loss is used in quantile regression for the median.

And of course the median (and therefore the $\ell_1$ minimizer) is much less influenced by the tails of your distribution.

The potential downside is that the median of your distribution will usually not be the same as the mean. That is: the $\ell_1$ minimizing prediction will not be the conditional expectation. That in turn is: it will be biased. The optimizing point prediction is a functional of the target distribution and depends on the eliciting error measure ([Kolassa, 2020](https://doi.org/10.1016/j.ijforecast.2019.02.017) - yes, that is self-promotion).

Note that "outliers" may well be *bona fide* members of your distribution. [Blindly removing outliers without good reason is not good practice.](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/476464/1352) This is related to the bias mentioned in the previous paragraph: don't just use an error measure because "it is useful as it excludes the effect of outliers". *Think* about which functional of the target distribution you want to elicit, and then choose an appropriate error measure.